# ROS Navigation: Modifying/creating a new layer of costmap

Tags: c++, navigation, ros

Currently I am trying to implement/modify layered costmaps. So we have a cost map generated by movebase from the /map topic that we are providing. Now say there is some change in the environment and I want to mark some regions as no-go regions.

These no-go regions will be reflected in a new layer of the costmap(that will be created by a node).  The coordinates of these regions should ideally  be subscribed to the ros node, and anytime a new set of coordinates are received on this node, the layer that we created previously should be updated.
I have tried going through the docs and tutorials on how to create a new layer, but I can't seem to get it to work with my use case.

Would love some pointers on how to implement this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you can try to follow the instructions from this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20New%20Layer) which might be useful to you.
If this doesn't work for you, you could share your current state of the code so we can elaborate more on the specific case that you have.